# Why is slain a past participle of slay?

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, old-english, middle-english, inflectional-morphology

Past participles in the English language usually end with *-ed*, but *slain* is one exception. Why can't we have just *slayed* rather than that and *slain*, too? And why can't *slain* be its very own verb?

Update: I'm not familiar with Old or Middle English.

Comment: There are many exceptions. https://www.englishpage.com/irregularverbs/irregularverbs.html

Comment: With _awake_, you have a choice: _awakened_ or _awoken_. But not _awaked_. With _set_, we have _The exams have been set_ but _The children have been setted._ But _droved_ is formed the regular way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no move to introduce regular versions of verb-forms as acceptable alternatives of irregular ones?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47982/why-is-there-no-move-to-introduce-regular-versions-of-verb-forms-as-acceptable-a)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've never come across _setted_ - I had to look it up to be sure it was a real word. (My spellcheck doesn't know it either!)

Comment: @Kate Bunting I think I checked it when our deputy head (1980s) first used it.  'Bid' is awkward/intriguing; 'I bid on that vase yesterday' but 'I bade them a fond farewell' ('bidded' is apparently non-standard). And I'd probably say 'The car speeded up and sped up th hill' if I had to complete a cloze test on verb forms. Then there's _Her lighted lamp lit the lane._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The link you provided does not answer my question.

Comment: @Eric Velazquez - I don't understand why you think "slain" could be a separate verb. What would it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *Slay* has always been a “strong” verb

The reason that we today say *slay, slew, slain* is that it was originally
a perfectly normal [strong class 6 verb in Old
English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_strong_verb#Class_6).

Strong verbs are those that show their past tense with a vowel mutation, like *know, knew* instead of **knowed* which would be a weak verb (and wrong of course).

Although strong verbs are more prevalent in Germanic languages, this vowel-mutating can also be found in Romance. For example, the Spanish verb *saber* meaning to know has a vowel change in its preterite forms, so *sabe* in the present unexpectedly becomes *supo* in the preterite. And the Spanish verb *dar* meaning to give has *da* in the present but a surprising *dé* in the preterite. You can even see this happening all the way back in its Latin root, *dare*, which has *dat* in the present but a surprising *dedit* in the perfect.

So strong verbs with vowel changes in the past tense are actually pretty common. Examples of strong class 6 Germanic verbs
that are still strong in English today include:

- draw, drew, drawn
- forsake, forsook, forsaken
- shake, shook, shaken
- slay, slew, slain
- swear, swore, sworn
- take, took, taken
- wake, woke, woken

As you see, *slay* isn’t quite like the others there, being a bit like
*draw, drew, drawn* but also a bit like *lie, lay, lain*, which was a
strong class 5 verb instead.

That’s because *slay* underwent a great deal of phonetic variation and
confusion in both Old and Middle English to get to us today.

In Old English
*slay* was *sléan*, or northern *slán, slá*.  Its past tense was *slóg*
or *slóh*, its plural was *slógon*, and its past participle was *slægen,
slegen,* or *slagen*. As you see, there’s already some variation all the
way back in Old English.

The OED notes that:

> All parts of the verb exhibit a great variety of Old English and
> Middle English forms, partly through natural phonetic development,
> and partly by assimilation to each other.
>
> The normal Middle English infinitives are *slē(n* from Old English
> *sléan*, and *slā(n*, *slō(n* from northern Old English *slán* or from Old
> Norse *slá*; the later forms *sley, slay* are due to the influence of the past
> participle.

So **that’s** why it’s *slay, slew, slain* today.

---

## The Historical Record of Forms

To help illustrate how tangled a history this verb has had in English, here is a **summary** of the OED’s tracing of its historical forms. I have omitted 98% of the actual text because those are illustrative citations.

> 1. *infinitive*.
>
>    - α. OE–ME **slean** (ME **sclean**, **sclein**), ME **sleen**; ME **slæn**, **slen**, **slene**.
>    - β. OE, ME **slæ**, ME–15 **sle** (ME **scle**), ME–15 **slee** (ME **sclee**), ME–15 **slea**.
>    - γ. (*northern* and *Scottish*) OE, ME **slan**, ME **slane**; OE, ME **slaa**, OE, ME–16 **sla** (ME **scla**), 15–16 **slae**, **slea**.
>    - δ. ME **slon**, **slone**; ME–15 **slo** (ME **sclo**), ME–15 **sloo**, ME–16 **sloe**.
>    - ε. ME **slaȝe**, **slayn**, ME–15 **slaye**, 15 **slaie**; ME–16 **sley** (15 **sleye**), ME– **slay** (15 **sleay**).
> 2. *present indicative*.
>
>    - **a.** *1st person singular* (also *subjunctive*) OE **slea**, OE, ME **slæ**, ME **sle**, 15 **slee**; 15 **sley(e**, **slaye**, 16– **slay**.
>    - **b.** *2nd person singular*
>
>      - α. OE **sles**, **slaes**, ME **slees**; ME **slaas**, **slos**.
>      - β. OE **slehst**, **slægst**, ME **sleast**, **sleest**; ME **slast**, 15– **slayest** (*poetic* **slay’st**).
>    - **c.** *3rd person singular*
>
>      - α. OE **sliehð**, **slihð**, **slyhð**, **slæhð**, ME **slehð**, **slekþ**.
>      - β. OE **slaeð**, ME **sleað**, **slað**; OE **sleð**, ME **sleþ**, ME–15 **sleth**, ME **slethe**; ME **sleeþ**, ME–15 **sleeth**; OE **slaes**, ME **sles(e**, ME **slees**, 16 **sleas**.
>      - γ. (*northern* and *Scottish*) *3rd person singular* ME **slaþ**; ME **slas**, **slase**, ME–15 **slaes**, **slais**. Also ME **sloð**, **sloys**.
>      - δ. ME **slaȝþ**, **sleith**, ME–15 **sleyth**, 15 **sleythe**, **sleayeth**, 15– (now *poetic*) **slayeth**; 15–16 **slayes** (*Scottish* **slayis**), 16– **slays**.
>    - **d.** *plural*.
>
>      - α. OE–ME **sleað**; ME **slen**, **sleen** (**scleen**); ME–15 **slea**, **sle**, **slee** (ME **sclee**); also *northern* ME **slees**.
>      - β. ME **slaȝe(ð**, 15 **sleye**, **slaye**, 16– **slay**.
>      - γ. (Also *subjunctive*) ME **sla**, **slaa**, **slo(e**.
> 3. *present subjunctive (2nd and 3rd person singular)*.
>
>    - α. OE **slae**, OE, ME **slea**, ME–15 **sle**, ME **slee**.
>    - β. *northern* ME **sla**, **slo**.
>    - γ. 15 **slaye**, 15– **slay**.
> 4. *imperative*.
>
>    - α. OE **sleh**, ME **sleih**, **sle**, ME–15 **slee**, 15 **sley**; OE **sleah**, **sleage**, ME **slea**; OE **slyh**, ME **slygh**.
>    - β. *singular* ME, 15 **sla**; ME **slo**, 16 *Scottish* **sloe**. *plural* ME **slas**, **slays**; **slo**, **slos**.
>    - γ. 15 **slaye**, 16– **slay**.
> 5. *past indicative*.
>
>    - α. *1st and 3rd person singular*OE, ME **sloh**, ME **slohw**; OE **slog**, **slogh**, ME **sloȝ**, **slooȝ** (ME **sloþ**), ME **sloȝe**; ME **slog**, **slogh** (ME **sloght**), **sloghe**, **sloch**; ME **slo**. *2nd person*OE **sloge**, ME **sloȝe**.
>    - β. *singular* ME **slowe** (ME **sclowe**), ME **sloue**; ME **slow** (ME **sclow**), ME **sloow**, **slou** (**sclou**).
>    - γ. *singular* ME **slouh**, **slowh**, **slouȝ**, **slowȝ(e**; ME **slough**, **sloughe**, **slowgh(e**. *plural* ME **sloughen**; ME **slowȝe**, **slowhe**, **sloughe**; ME **slouȝ**, **slough**.
>    - δ. *singular* ME **sluȝ**, **sluȝe**, 15–16 **slue**; ME **slewȝ**, *Scottish* **sleuch** (**sleucht**), 15 **scleuȝe**; ME– **slew**, ME–15 **slewe**. Also *2nd person* 15–16 **slew’st**.
> 6. *past subjunctive* OE **sloge**, *plural* **slogen**, ME **sloȝe**, **sluȝe**, **slowe**.
>
>    - α. (a) OE **geslægen**, **geslegen**, ME **i-slæȝ en**, **i-sleien**, **i-slein**, **i-**, **y-slayn**, **y-sclayn**, **y-slayne**, 15 **y-slaine**.
>    - β. ME **i-**, **hii-sleȝe**, **i-slehȝe**; ME **sleie**, **sleye**, **slaye**, **slay**, **scley**.
>    - γ. OE **geslagen**, ME **i-slaȝen**, **i-sclawen**, **i-slawen**, **y-slawen**; ME **slaȝen**, **slawen**, **slaun**, **slawn**.
>    - δ. ME **i-**, **y-slaȝe**, **i-slawe**, ME–15 **y-slawe**; 15 **y-slaw**; ME **slawe** (ME **sclawe**).
>    - ε. ME **i-slæn**, **sleen**, 15 **slene**.
>    - ζ. *northern* and *Scottish* ME **slan**, ME–15 **slane**, 15 **y-slane**.
>    - η. ME **slon**, ME–15 **slone**, ME **sloon**.

Isn’t that incredible? Aren’t you relieved that we’ve been left with nothing more complicated than the standard *slay, slew, slain* today? I know I sure am!

Answer (score 1):

> Why is slain a past participle of slay?

Because it derives from Old English.

Modern English comes from a mixture of languages, French, Latin, Greek and Germanic.

Old English is a Germanic language. The verb "to slay" has changed over time but is Germanic in origin. Today it is called an irregular verb because it does not not have the regular inflections you might expect.

**Present tense in modern English**

I/you/we/they *slay*

he *slays*

**Simple past (modern)**

I *slew*, etc.

**Participle (modern)**

I have *slain*, etc.

---

**Historical note**

If you go back to the 1600s when the King James Bible was published, you'll find an older form that is described in the following link. It includes "thou slayest", and "he slayeth".

[conjugation of slay](http://www.majstro.com/Web/Majstro/taleninfo/CompEng/onregww_slay.php)

Already in modern day English you may see "slayed" used as simple past and as past participle among people who don't have a classical education. It is quite possible that this and other irregular verbs will become regularized as the century progresses.

Comment: Where (Early) Modern English has *thou slayest* or *thou slay’st*, Old
English once had *þú slægst* using a *g* that perforce became a *ȝ* in
Middle English and thence a simple *y* in Modern English. It really all
makes fine sense viewed diachronically even if it just completely buggers
the brain under synchronic analysis uninformed by history. :)

Comment: A classical education?

Comment: @EricVelazquez A [classical education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_education_movement#Grammar) included first and foremost in the Grammar section of the *trivium* a command of Ancient Greek and Latin. :)